# Loop with 2 conditions is exiting when 1 condition is met

Tags: c

I want the loop to exit when both strncmp() and check() return 0, meaning they both found a match. The problem is, when check() returns 0 and strncmp() does not return 0 the loop is exiting.

```
while (strncmp(buf, match, 3) != 0 && check(buf[3]) != 0)
{
}
```

I have checked the values in buf and match and they do not match when it exits. buf[3] does match when it exits.

Comment: I did never go to the trouble of learning precedence of logical operators. I always use parenthesis: `while((strncmp(buf, match, 3) != 0) && (check(buf[3]) != 0)) { /* ... */ }` to avoid surprises.

Comment: Does not make sense. Please show us your test case.

Comment: When you say "condition is met", strncmp(buf, match, 3) != 0 returns false and so does check(buf[3]) != 0 ? Could you provide a sample of buf and match variables, also what's in check() ?

Comment: *"Loop with 2 conditions is exiting when 1 condition is met"* -- the loop *continues* when both conditions are met. It *ends* when only one or none are met.

Comment: What does check() do and why not just use && buf[3] != 0 )   ?

Comment: Can you give some example values which cause the loop to end when it shouldn't, and show what `check()` does?

Comment: @pmg I tried it with parenthesis but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Asoub When I say the condition is met I mean that strncmp and check both return 0, which is when they both find a match.

Comment: "I have made sure condition 1 is not matching when it exits" If it does not match, the `&&` fails, the second half is not even executed and the loop terminates. Why are you surprised? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `&&` so you're saying both `strncmp(buf, match, 3)` ***and*** `check(buf[3]) != 0` must be met in order for the loop to continue. To get the result you specified you should use `||`

Comment: That is not what OP meant I think. The use of `&&` is intended and desired.

Comment: @Elyasin I thought `I have made sure condition 1 is not matching when it exits so I don't understand why it is exiting.` was a a good reason to think he meant that.

Comment: I think you're right if I'm honest. it looks like the OP may be confused about how while loops work - that it's "**UNTIL** the statement is true", not "**UNLESS** the statement is true"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want the loop to exit when  both strncmp() and check() return 0, meaning they both found a match. The problem is, when check() returns 0 but strncmp() does not return 0, the loop is exiting.

Answer (score 3):

This loop runs as long as

1. `buf` and `match` differ somewhere in the first 3 characters, **AND**
2. `check(buf[3])` is nonzero

Is that what you want? In other words, the loop exits when either

1. `buf` and `match` share the same three initial characters **OR**
2. `check(buf[3])` is zero

> I want the loop to exit when both strncmp() and check() return 0

Then you can rewrite the loop to be very easy to verify against your requirement:

```
for(;;) {
 ...
 if (strncmp(buf, match, 3) == 0 && check(buf[3]) == 0)
    break;
 ...
}
```

Now place the negated condition in the controlling expression of the loop:

```
while (! (strncmp(buf, match, 3) == 0 && check(buf[3]) == 0) ) {
   ...
}
```

If you are somewhat into computer science, you realize that `not(A and B)` is--per [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)--equivalent to `(not A) or (not B)`. This finally yields:

```
while (strncmp(buf, match, 3) != 0 || check(buf[3]) != 0) {
}
```

So your error was using `&&` instead of `||` for the logical operator.

Answer (score 2):

u can try this ...

```
int c,d;
while ((c=strncmp(buf, match, 3) != 0) && (d=check(buf[3]) != 0))
{}
```

Description:

strncmp() will return a value that have to store in a var..if u don't do then how it will compare with 0..same as also check().

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Especially those without any format.